# CiviMail UI is in a different language

Tags: civimail, localisation, i18n

We have localization set up to use English (default) and Spanish. We have been having an issue where CiviMail is being partially translated to Spanish. The rest of Civi remains in English and the language switcher is still set to English. Has anyone else had this issue or know of things to check to resolve this bug? CiviCRM 5.41.2 Drupal 7.
[image]

Comment: do you have mosaico on? does this happen if you try an email via Mosaico and does it occur if you try an email via Traditional Mailing?

Comment: @petednz-fuzion we do have mosaico turned on. This does happen when sending through mosaico. I haven't noticed if it does it through Traditional Mail as well. We don't use that as often so it may also have issues and no one has noticed it. For now, the issue seems to have resolved itself, but I'd like to figure out what is causing it in the first place.